# Zend AJAX with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, zend-framework

I'd like to use pure Javascript httprequest to post a message to a controller/action in Zend and get back a response that I can process back in the page with a callback function, classically.

Two questions:

1. how can I format the POST string taking into account the baseurl imposed by Zend (in the classical case I point to a php file).
2. what should I do - the simplest possible (I understand there are several possible implementations) - in the action method so that to return a response.

Again, no jQuery, JSON, prototype or other library.

The use case is the following: I have a view with a form section. One of the inputs is a select drop down list, I click on an item of that list, I trigger an Ajax request to controller/action and get back instantly from the server a value that I update a text area with.

Comment: JSON is no library. It is a data format like XML.

Comment: Just wondering if you could explain your aversion to using a library? They get written so that you don't have to rewrite 'classic' js like this over and over again.

Comment: About JSON: I want to make suer not using special Zend objects.

Comment: About not uisng libs: it's not an aversion, just a requirement for other related processing on the JavaScriot side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you post to is all dependent on your controllers and modules structure, so that makes it hard for us to give you a detailed answer.  But for a simple example, try this out.

form post to http://domain.com/index/textarea

**the controller: IndexController.php**

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction() {

    }

    public function textareaAction() {
        // if you are using layouts
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

        // process your post here
        $var = $this->_getParam('posted_var');

        $this->view->text =  '$var processed'; 
    }
}
```

**the view: textarea.phtml**

```
<?php

echo $this->text;
```

What ever is in your view, will then be returned to your JavaScript.

For a better implementation read up on [AjaxContext switching](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html), which will allow you to use JSON, which means you can drop the view file, and ZF will simply return a JSON encoded string for you.

Comment: Thanks. In fact I did it in the same pattern you mention. AjaxContext better not to use when you want to handle 100% by yourself; that's from experience. So layout disabling and JSON encoding must be done as per the documentation in the action method.